# stripe express resume onboarding using Oauth /

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to resume the onboarding registration flow for a marketplace account creation. users can create accounts, returning accountIds, but they can validate the account creation without providing all their necessary files, making their account on hold. I would like them to be able to go back to their stripe account / or to resume their account creation on a later stage so they can provide missing files.

I have tried

```
exports.loginLink = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const loginLink = await stripe.accounts.createLoginLink(
  req.query.state
  );
  console.log('url login link  ----> ' + loginLink);
  console.log('url login link  ----> ' + res);
  return res.send(loginLink);
})
```

But it returns :
Your client does not have permission to get URL /createAccountLink&state=***** from this server.
I guess it s an Oauth issue. Is there any step I should add ? (like connecting a user with his accountId for example ?)

PS I can t use V1 since it requires our Stripe account to be validated, and it s still pending ..

Answer (score 0):

When onboarding Express accounts with Connect, you should be using [Account Links](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links). [Login Links](https://stripe.com/docs/api/account/create_login_link) are for gating access for onboarded accounts to their Express dashboard.

When handling users who have not completed the onboarding steps, [you should generate a new Account Link](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#handle-users-not-completed-onboarding) and forward them accordingly to complete the process.

Comment: they complete de onboarding steps, but they can complete without sending all the required documents (Id copy for example), So their accountId is created. What I am trying to do is to get them to access their express Dashboards using login Links

Comment: What does `req.query.state` look like?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, I pass the accountID through the State object

Comment: @YannMassard Can you please share the actual `req.query.state` object? Is your `stripe` object using the keys from your Platform account?